# How to select a subset of rows in pandas with a certain starting value and certain ending value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In pandas, it's possible to return subsets of rows using like this:

`df[:6]`

which would with the dataset I'm using return:

```
weekday                CO_level           ...

0 Monday               Very high
1 Tuesday              Low
2 Wednesday            Low
3 Saturday             Medium
4 Sunday               High
5 Thursday             Low
```

I did a bit of data cleaning and removed all rows w/ null values which resulted in the rows having some missing weekdays but I want to visualize the CO_level for one entire week Monday - Sunday.

My question is: how can I go through the rows and return the first instance or all instance (doesn't really matter) of 7 *consecutive* rows with Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday values?

So that it could look something like this:

```
weekday                CO_level           ...

345 Monday               Very high
346 Tuesday              Low
347 Wednesday            Low
348 Thursday             Medium
349 Friday               High
350 Saturday             Low
351 Sunday               Low
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Yefet's answer looks good.  Here's a different approach:

```
days = ['Monday',
 'Tuesday',
 'Wednesday',
 'Thursday',  
'Friday',  
 'Saturday', 
 'Sunday']

for i in range(len(df)):
    test_days = df['weekday'][i:i+7].to_list()
    if test_days == days:
        week_df = df.iloc[i:i+7,:]
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the weekday offset per day.  Extract seven days at a time.  Calculate the start - end date in days and keep if the number is seven days.  advance the start date by one day and repeat the process.